# Files disappeared after renaming folder to .nomedia in Android, so what happend?

Tags: android, storage, file-management, data-recovery

I renamed a folder in my Android device to ".nomedia" in order to exclude its contents from the media scanner. However, after doing so, the entire folder seems to have disappeared from my device. I've checked various file management apps and even tried searching for it through a computer connection, but the folder is still disappear.

Is it possible that the folder was deleted after being renamed to ".nomedia"? I checked the storage on Google Play Store, which shows my device has a total of 242GB, but when I connect it to the computer, it only displays 225GB.

[Computer display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDYiK.png)

[google play display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1ltp.jpg)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You forgot to post the code with which you changed the foldername.

Comment: `but the folder remains inaccessible.`? Huuu .. first you said it had disappeared. That does not match.

Comment: Which android device you are using?

Comment: Show hidden files enabled?

Comment: I am sorry for that，i am not good at English，i mean when i connect to the computer，i still can‘t find the folder. i just use the file control system to change the foldername, not use the code to change it. @blackapps

Comment: I show the hidden files, but i still can't find it. The files may be hidden or have been deleted after i change the foldername to **.nomedia**.I am sorry for the question i asked is not clear, i am a English beginner. I am not sure the situation is which one. The data is not important. I just want to know what happened, the folder including its files is whether still exists or not?  By the way，my android device is Redmi K50 which is made by a chinese brand you may not know. @blackapps

Comment: My android device is Redmi K50 which is made by a chinese brand you may not know.@DeveloperSunshine

Comment: Of course you can rename a folder like that. I just tried. Further you are in the wrong forum as this is no programming question. Moderators are sleeping again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place an empty **file** named ".nomedia" in the **folder** that should not be scanned for media. On my Phone I can create and delete folders with the name ".nomedia" with a file manager without any problems. It seems that you have deleted the folder after all as a result of mismanipulation.

Comment: A .nomedia file does not prevent from scanning by media store any more.